# Is there a rule for assigning polarities to resistors or is it truly arbitrary?

Tags: circuit-analysis, polarity, mesh-analysis

Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to circuit analysis. I'm still rather confused about how you're supposed to assign polarities to resistors in a voltage. I've been told time and time again that polarities are assigned arbitrary and that no matter what end you choose to have higher potential, the math always checks out in the end. However, I've come across many circuits in my textbook where this was not the case.
For example, in this circuit I'm supposed to use mesh analysis to solve currents i1 and i2. I've assigned the polarities as follows:
[image]

However, according to my textbook, this arrangement yields incorrect results and the way I've found to get the right answers is to arrange the circuit this way:
[image]

This makes me think there is some kind of rule about assigning polarities I'm forgetting. However, I've scanned my textbook and looked online to find no general rule, hence my confusion. Is it something to do with the flow of current? I was also told that that too was to be arbitrarily assigned, so I'm unsure. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain things to me. Thanks for reading

Comment: Be aware, though. In your specific circuit, just ignore the right side power supply (remove it.) Then you find that the voltage across the 12 Ohm resistor is `12/(12+4+2)*45=30`. So there will be no current through the 30 V supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your first diagram and run with it.

[image]

What I've done is added green and blue colored currents to the diagram. They show you the direction of the assumed current in each resistor, based upon your assignments for their signs.

Now, we know the following with respect to the loop currents:

$$\begin{align*}
i_{R_1}&=i_1\\
i_{R_2}&=-i_1\\
i_{R_3}&=i_1-i_2\\
i_{R_4}&=i_2\\
i_{R_5}&=-i_2
\end{align*}$$

So the mesh equations should be written as:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1-R_1\cdot i_1-R_3\cdot\left(i_1-i_2\right) + R_2\cdot -i_1 &= 0
\\\\
R_3\cdot\left(i_1-i_2\right)-R_4\cdot i_2-V_2+R_5\cdot -i_2 &= 0
\end{align*}$$

That's what I meant by ruling yourself with an **iron-fist** (in comment, since deleted.) You can ignore the passive sign convention, with respect to the loop currents, and just make any random assignment for the signs. But if you do that, then you need to recognize what this implies for the sign of the loop current that you then apply.

The way you probably ***should*** do it is like this:

[image]

Note that I've used the passive sign convention on the resistors (as seen by the loop currents.) Note also that \$R_3\$ has ***two*** and not ***one*** plus sign assigned to it. One is for \$i_1\$'s perspective and the other is for \$i_2\$'s perspective. And they are differently placed.

Now, the mesh equations are:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1-R_1\cdot i_1-R_3\cdot\left(i_1-i_2\right) - R_2\cdot i_1 &= 0
\\\\
-R_3\cdot\left(i_2-i_1\right)-R_4\cdot i_2-V_2-R_5\cdot i_2 &= 0
\end{align*}$$

The caveat above is that in the first equation the current in \$R_3\$ is taken as \$i_1-i_2\$ but in the second equation it is instead taken as \$i_2-i_1\$.

*(That's because when considering the \$i_2\$ loop, and the fact that the passive sign convention has a drop taking place here, this means that \$i_2\$ is taken as positive and, well, then \$i_1\$ is pointing opposite to it so it must be subtracted.)*

Answer (score 1):

Polarity does not matter when you label the resistors.

You can arbitrariy choose a direction for current in a loop and polarity for each resitor.

But then you have to put a positive or negative signs in your equations based on how you labeled the resistors and how you chose the current direction.

If you look at the left loop only, you have chosen the current to flow out of positive supply, which is a logical choise, but arbitrary.

Then you have labeled the two resistors to assume positive side where the current enters in. Again a logical choise.

But for the third resistor, you chose the polarity so that current enters in from the assumed negative terminal. This is weird because why would you do that if you didn't do that for the previous two resistors. But it means that the resistor has negative sign current through it to have an opposite polarity in the direction you chose, so your equations need to have a different sign for that resistor.

Answer (score 1):

It's arbitrary but you have to be consistent. Assuming a voltage of the opposite polarity of the assumed current is theoretically possible but it gets SUPER CONFUSING. The reason is because you aren't just assuming the direction of current and voltage drop.

What you're really doing is assuming the current direction and whether the component is a source or a load. So what you are essentially doing when you assume those voltage polarities for the 3Ohm and 4Ohm resistors is that you are assuming they are sources. This makes it really confusing when you *know* they are resistors and must be loads.

If you have a bunch of unknown components, it's tricky enough to keep track of all the assumptions you make as to whether an unknown component is a source or load. But if you do it like your first image where the assumptions wrong on on purpose it's even more confusing. It's difficult enough to keep track of that it's often easier to assume every unknown is either a load or a source. That way when you are at the end there is consistent meaning to your signs rather than depending on an independent assumption for each component.

I test this every few years and it's confusing enough that whenever I test this with the simplest of circuits I'm never able to do it because you're fighting yourself. You end up needing to keep track of every specifically different assumption you make for every component. It's like those tests where you're supposed to say the colour that the text is written in, and not the colour that the text writes out.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been told time and time again that polarities are assigned arbitrary and that no matter what end you choose to have **higher potential**, the math always checks out in the end

NOOOO!

When you choose the polarity labeling for a resistor, you're choosing which end is your **reference** end. That end may have higher or lower potential, the maths will check out in the end to tell you.

It's **because** resistors don't have a natural polarity, that you have to assign one to them, in order that the maths can work. Just keep it consistent from the beginning to the end of the process. If it turns out the voltage across a resistor is negative, so be it.

I like working with things the 'right way round', so do most other people. If you happen to choose a polarity where the resistor has a positive voltage across it and current through it (or have the skills or experience to spot that ahead of calculations), then your equations will have fewer '-' signs to keep track of, which is nice, but not essential.